# placing NOT problem

Tags: negation

In the sentence

> Yes, at least financially speaking, your opinion sounds right, even if ...

is grammatically right adding *not* this way

> Yes, at least financially *not* speaking, your opinion sounds right, even if ...

or *not* cannot be placed there, so is valid

> Yes, at least *not* financially speaking, your opinion sounds right, even if ...

?

Answer (score 5):

The first example is not syntactically correct.

I would suggest something like

> Yes, apart from your view on finances, your opinion sounds right, even if .

or

> Yes, except from the part dealing with finances, your opinion sounds right, even if .

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the insertion of the word *not*, in either place. The expression [*adverb*] *speaking* is used often, and it's almost idiomatic. For example:

> - Generally speaking, it's rainy in Seattle.
> - Technically speaking, the Internet isn't down – it's your connection that's down.
> - Financially speaking, driving an ice cream truck isn't a good career path.
> - Ethically speaking, I had to tell the buyer that the engine is leaking oil.

This construct means, essentially, *from an* [*adjective*] *point of view...* So, these sentences would mean:

> - From a general point of view, it's rainy in Seattle.
> - From a technical standpoint, the Internet isn't down – it's your connection that's down.
> - From a financial perspective, driving an ice cream truck isn't a good career path.
> - As a matter of ethics, I had to tell the buyer that the engine is leaking oil.

If I wanted to somehow negate this construct, I would restructure the sentence, rather than using the word *not*.

> - It usually rains in Seattle, **but today it's sunny**.
> - Technically, the internet isn't down – **but I know what you mean.**
> - You won't make a fortune driving an ice cream truck, **but I can see how the job might be fun**.
> - I could have withheld the oil problem, **but that would have been unethical.**

Getting back to your example, if you are refuting the person from a perspective that's **not** the financial perspective, then you should pinpoint that perspective:

> - Yes, at least **morally** speaking, your opinion sounds right, even if ...

Alternatively, if you want to emphasize that your statement is excluding the financial perspective, you could word that in a manner such as one of these:

> - Yes, **financial considerations aside**, your opinion sounds right, even if ...
> - Yes, **disregarding financial matters for the moment**, your opinion sounds right, even if ...

but I would strongly recommend **against** *Yes, not financially speaking*...

Answer (score 2):

The latter sentence is better, but I would say something like "Yes, at least, speaking of other things than finances....".